# Android startActivity() works for one class but not the other

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The app that I am developing is messing with me. I have three activities at the moment (all of which are defined in the manifest), that all transition into eachother i.e intro-->activity1-->activity2. The transition from the intro to the first activity works fine using:

```
public void GOTOGPS(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.button1: startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), StreetLightOutageActivity.class));//Jump to StreetLightOutageActivity (main.xml)
    default: break;

    }//switch
}//GOTOGPS
```

However, the method in my second activity "StreetLightOutageActivity" that is used to go to my third activity does not work:

```
 public void GOTOCAMERA1(View v)
{

    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.picturebutton: startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Camera.class));
    default: break;

    }//switch

}//GOTOCAMERA1
```

LogCat gives me an ActivityNotFoundException:

```
05-17 15:51:41.292: E/AndroidRuntime(534): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {sl.reporter/android.hardware.Camera}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

and then an InvocationTargetException which I assume stems from the previous exception:

```
05-17 15:51:41.292: E/AndroidRuntime(534): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Now what is really getting me, is that if I modify the method to transition from my introscreen to my second activity to go to "Camera.class" instead of StreetLightOutageActivity.class, It works.

finally, here is my manifest just in case it helps,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="sl.reporter"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
     <activity
         android:name=".StreetLightOutageActivity">
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".Camera">
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".Introscreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case R.id.picturebutton: startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Camera.class));
```

I think in the above code you want to use `sl.reporter.Camera` class, but mistakenly you end up using `android.hardware.Camera`.

Comment: Holy cow, I leave for lunch and come back and you already fixed it. I removed "android.hardware.Camera" and used "sl.reporter.Camera" like you said and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I am glad your problem is solved. But why don't you select my answer as correct? :)

Comment: Sorry, This is my first post on StackOverflow. Just did it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong import for your purported Camera activity class:

```
  Unable to find explicit activity class {sl.reporter/android.hardware.Camera};
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely are referencing the Android built in camera Class instead of your own

Make sure in your imports you don't have

```
import android.graphics.Camera;
```

or

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

if so delete it and make sure when you import your Camera class it is pointing to your own..

ex.

```
import sl.reporter.Camera;
```

Comment: better yet, change the name of your activity